# Google CRUD Migration from SQL API to Fusion Tables API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I used [Ferris Argyle's CRUD from the Google Apps Developer Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-fusion-tables-with-apps-script.html) and now must migrate this SQL API to Fusion Tables API.  The full code is [here](https://sites.google.com/a/ferrisargyle.com/blog-posts/using-fusion-tables-with-apps-script).  So far my efforts have left me with a code 404 error and lots of this:' `<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>`Not Found.'  Ideally this example CRUD would be updated by Google but lacking an update perhaps someone could offer guidance.

What i've updated from the migration guide.

1. Turned on API, Removed numberic ID's, Updated libraries (None for me), updated URL end point.
2. added '&alt=csv' to query parameter.
3. added '&key=*MyEncriptedAPIKey*'.
4. I am unsure if OAuth in the CRUD must be updated.
5. I am unsure of the relationship between API Key and OAuth, do i need both or one.

Can anyone look at the example CRUD and tell me what i'm missing?  i'm a novice with Javascripts, Google Apps, OAuth so examples or links are welcome.

thanks,

Scott "if it ain't broken don't fix it" B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Google Apps Script doesn't currently doesn't have native support OAuth2 authentication, which is required to by the new Fusion Tables API to access private data. Some users have had success implementing parts of the OAuth2 flow themselves in Apps Script, but as a novice this may not be feasible. If you are only accessing public data then you should be able to get by just using the API key.